# Running Chrome with Windows Java 8 Plugin

Tags: wine, java, google-chrome

We are using DocuSign API inside our Java solution in Linux environment. So far, so good.

Now we are trying to enable users to sign using a PKI certificate but DocuSign installs:

1. A Chrome plugin (that's fine);
2. A DocuSign PKI plugin that is an EXE and requires Java 8.

I tried installing Java 8 using Wine, but couldn't. 64 bits version fails silently and 32 bits version complains about Windows version and also fails.

Given that, 2 questions:

1. Can I install JRE 8 on Ubuntu? How?
2. Even if I can install JRE, will Linux Chrome work with this DocuSign plugin? I don't think so.

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome does not support any Java plugins.

Answer (score 1):

## Install JRE 8

If you want to install the proprietary Oracle JRE 8 (and not openjdk), you can go on the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and download the `jre-8u121-linux-x64.tar.gz` file, and then install it using the [instruction here](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/java_proprietaire), or, simpler, just add the ppa and install oracle-java8-installer :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y oracle-java8-installer
```

## DocuSign Plugin

I suspect that the `.exe` contains some `.jar` files. Could you try to extract them with something like this :

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip*
p7zip e <your file>.exe
```

and see if it contains some `.jar` files ? Since I don't know how you get your file it's pretty hard to test, so put in comments what you get.